# Можно ли как-то пометить запускаемый процесс?

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Допустим, у меня есть программа А, которая может создавать n(ое) количество процессов программы B. При запуске процессов программы В я получаю их айдишники, по которым я их потом могу убить. Все ок. Но иногда происходят такие ситуации, что айдишники процессов В мне не доступны. И по имени процесса В я тоже не могу убить процессы, так как рискую убить процессы другой инстанции. Вопрос: можно ли как-то помечать процессы? Засунуть туда какую-то свою пользовательскую информацию, чтобы потом по ней отыскивать их и килить?

Comment: Можете рассказать, а какие это ситуации, когда ID процесса Вам не доступно?

Comment: Допустим, в случае, если пользователь закрыл приложение. Или же произошла ошибка, и приложение повалилось. Также я сам могу зайти и закрыть приложение, сделать апдейт. Приложение A я-то закрою, а вот созданные процессы приложения В будет проблематично, т.к. в одной сессии могут работать несколько приложений А со своими запущенными процессами В.

Comment: можно бродкастом послать сообщение, нужные приложения (то есть Ваши) отзовутся.

В линуксе есть возможность запускать в группе, и соответственно обращаться к этой группе (например, завершить все процессы).

Comment: бродкаст интересное решение, если бы только приложение B было бы написано мной. Про запуск в группе на винде не чего не нашел.
В общем пока сделал такое решение, создаю локальный файл и записываю(перезаписываю) туда все id своих процессов. Выглядит не очень красиво, но поставленную задачу это решает.

Comment: можно пойти хитрее - создать фиктивного пользователя и запускать приложения от его имени. Да, придется чуточку попотеть, но результат будет хороший.

Также получается дополнительный контроль за правами. Приложение будет иметь свой личный Document&Settings.

Более того, если кто то другой запустит приложение, то оно будет запущено от другого пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если процесс запускается и убивается одной и той же программой, используй объект Process, который возвращает вызов Process.Start.
2. Если запуск происходит как-то из вне, но ты это можешь изменять, то можно передать процессу B лишние параметры командной строки. Естественно, подразумевается, что программа B их проигнорирует. Если это не так и изменять программу B нет возможности, то этот способ не подходит.
3. Если запуск происходит через промежуточные шаги вне программы, но инициатором всё же является программа, причём, ни одно из звеньев цепочки не завершается до момента, когда надо прибивать процесс, то можно проверять дерево процессов на то, есть ли среди предков программа A.

Если ситуация не попала в рассмотренные варианты, то нужно более детальное описание.

Answer (score 0):

У процесса есть свойство `StartInfo`, из которого можно узнать, с какими аргументами командной строки был запущен процесс.

Кроме того, Вы можете сохранить полученные айдишники процессов у себя, а при убиении процесса каждый раз искать процесс по айдишнику заново.

Можете использовать для доступа к процессам функции `WinAPI` `SendMessage` или `PostMessage`, передавая им сообщение со своим, нестандартным кодом, а в процессах сделать невидимое главное окно, которое будет это сообщение обрабатывать. В обработчике этого сообщения Вы можете записать в сообщение некое число, чтобы получить его в вызываемой программе.

Comment: На StartInfo возлагал надежды, но по каким то причинам, он оказывается пустой. 

По сохранению айдишников, именно так сейчас и делаю(начал делать). Создаю файлик, в котором ведется учет, к какому экземпляру приложения А, относятся айдишники процессов В. Это все работает, и работает не плохо. Но как то не красиво. 

По WinAPI SendMessage или PostMessage, спасибо. Попробую покурить по ним информацию.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что проблема в том, что Вам нужно как-то обрабатывать ситуацию, когда Вы перезапускаете свой пускач?

Comment: Да, действительно, `StartInfo` у уже запущенного процесса нужных данных не содержит. Вместо этого посмотрите вот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504208/how-to-read-command-line-arguments-of-another-process-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Process.Start` возвращает вам экземпляр типа `Process`. Используйте этот экземпляр, чтобы завершить именно тот процесс, который вы запустили.